# Can I create a SharePoint 2010 workflow without using Visio 2010 Premium?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, visio

What I am trying to do here is to create a workflow using Visio 2010 for SharePoint 2010. Everything I keep finding indicates that I have to use Visio 2010 Premium in order to create a workflow in SharePoint 2010. Is there a way to create a workflow using a non-premium Visio 2010 Office product, or must I use the Premium version of Visio for the workflow to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I learned trying to create a SharePoint 2010 form using Visio 2010. The only way to do this is to use Visio 2010 Premium Edition. I found this out through videos, white papers and still wanted to push the limits on my own. So, I created a basic Visio form and tried saving it with the extension (.vwi) which SharePoint designer flagged me when I first tried importing the form into Designer. So I re-saved the form with the new extension with the double quotes around the name and extension "Drawing1.vwi" so the ".vsd" extension wouldn't add itself to the name. This didn't work. SharePoint Designer wouldn't accept the form even with a new and correct extension, its as though it was programed to know that I was trying to do a work around.

So, Visio 2010 Premium is a must. However if you find a work around that I may have missed, please let me know, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010 too.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can create a workflow in Designer, but I have been advised to use Visio and the videos I found indicate that I must have Visio 2010 Premium for workflows with visio to work properly with sharepoint... I just want to know if there is a work around, if I can create a flow chat in visio that is no 'Microsoft SharePoint' and still pull it through designer and how accurate it would be. Thank You.